# Opening LiveCare by Commnad line

Tags: vb.net

i have this problem
I have to Launch the  remote application LiveCare by a program in Visual Basic, but i can't find online a way for open it
can someone know how to solve it?

Comment: What is LiveCare? A web application (ie: web page)? A desktop application? Please  [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it's an application similar to Team Viewer, where you can connect to other PCs

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0)